# Xunit 1.9.1 to xunit 2.1.0 migeration (IOC / Dependency injection)

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, autofac, xunit2

I need your expert advice

**Background:**
I am migerating my Xunit 1.9.1 to  2.1.0. I am using the following extensions
- Xunit.ioc.ninject
- xunit.ioc.autofac

**Problem:**
These two are not supported anymore.. I am using 
 - IDependencyResolverBootstrapper
 - Xunit.Ioc.Autofac.TestsModule

**Question:**
what would be the best way/ extension to replace